# When is it acceptable to combine expressions of probability with expressions of expectation/planning?

Tags: adverbs, is-it-a-rule

While working on expressions of probability with some ESL students, the question came up of whether it'd be ok to say something such as:

> **Hopefully**, they will **probably** help us out in the future.

My knee jerk reaction to this sentence is to say that you should pick one or the other, either 'hopefully' or 'probably' but I haven't been able to find a thouroughly well-reasoned explanation as to why that is the case. Some combinations are obviously nonsensical in that one expression clashes with the other, for example:

> **Hopefully**, this will **certainly** be useful.

Or

> We are **planning to** **definitely** complete the assignment in time.

There's an inherent sense of uncertainty in 'hopefully' and 'planning to' that doesn't match the adverbs used further down the sentence. However, it wouldn't strike me as odd to see an action framed as a plan or expectation being used together with an adverb that denotes some level of uncertainty, like this:

> We are **aiming to** **maybe** finish in 2 hours, 3 at the most.

Would this be an exception to the rule or is it simply a matter of the terms used not clashing in the perception of certainty/confidence they create? I'd love to know if there is some kind of formal rule or study that explores this in more detail.

Comment: What’s the “rule” that this would seem an exception to?

Comment: That is precisely what I'd like to know. There is no rule that I'm aware of but I also cannot think of many other ways of using those terms that would sound acceptable.

Comment: To hope something will probably happen is not logical.

Comment: They will probably help us out in the future. I hope they do, anyway.

Comment: Careful with hopefully versus it is hoped.

Comment: There are many ways you can use multiple adverbs of this kind, generally for emphasis or to get your point across, to express desires, worries, to demand or hedge. It's certainly hard to give general rules, but something like "maybe" can be inserted a lot to indicate doubt, and "definitely" is often inserted for rhetorical purposes. It's also possible to have a desire but be unsure if all of it will happen, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue at play here is the semantic element to which the hope applies.

In your first example, the author intends to pin *hope* to *help*. Semantically, however, they've pinned *hope* to *probable help*, which is something quite different. Let's put this into perspective:

- The casino hopes that the algorithm will (only) probably succeed because if it always definitely succeeds, nobody would be willing to play against it.

The first example is not trying to express hope for uncertain help - it is trying to express hope (perhaps even an uncertain hope) in definite help. This discrepancy between the sentence's objective semantics and what is perceived as the speaker's intent makes the sentence sound awkward.

The second example "hopefully, they will certainly be useful" is a little better, but there is still a gap between hoping for the certainty of usefulness and hoping for the usefulness itself.

Your third example about "planning to definitely succeed" functions in a similar manner. "Definitely succeed" is used as a metonym for the success itself. The level of awkwardness in the sentence depends on how well the metonymy is accepted.

The third example "aiming to maybe finish in 2 hours" is a little better again. One can still argue for a difference between "maybe finish" and "finish", but the phrasing is sufficiently malleable that it can be read as merely an alternate way of saying "aiming to finish in maybe 2 hours". This is analogous to accepted phrases such as "all that glitters is not gold", where the qualifying word "all/maybe" is commonly understood to apply semantically to something other than what strict logic would dictate.

So to answer your question: it is "acceptable to combine expressions of probability with expressions of expectation/planning" when the probability is the semantic target of the expectation/planning. It is also somewhat acceptable when the only reason the semantic target of the expectation/planning differs from the intended target is an established quirk of expression.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you wonder if you can use two adverbs naturally at the same in a sentence.

You should keep in mind that "adverb" is just an additional information in a sentence(not the core).

> Hopefully,
>
> > > they will probably help us out in the future.
> > > (I can't find what's wrong)
> > > Hopefully and probably, they will help us out in the future.(Alternative)

> Hopefully,
>
> > > this will certainly be useful.
> > > (the same as above)

Hopefully and certainly, they will be useful.(Alternative)

> > We are planning to
> >
> > > > definitely complete the assignment in time. (same)

It's important that the speaker choose the right word which is natural and idiomatic.

This question is: not objective but subjective and not quantitative but qualitative

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but my problem lies precisely in finding a sensible way to formalize this qualitative aspect and explain to ESL learners what would feel natural, especially since none of these sentences are grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

There's a name for repetition that adds nothing: [**tautology**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/tautology).

> Oxford Lexico example for tautology: It is conceivable that the key to truth lies in tautology and redundancy.

Hopefulness and probability are too close in meaning, like Big Fat Greek Wedding, where the tautology is funny. Other times, you need tautology for emphasis, like "Cash only. No checks."

Also, *hopefully*, as here, is notorious for not applying where it sits: While **you are hopeful that they** will help, you say "Hopefully they." So, are they hopeful that they will help?

Comment: *hopefully, as here,* seems to be a free modifier (also called a sentence adverb). It modifies the whole main clause.

Comment: They are different in meaning. 'Probably' is a modal evaluation, proffering an estimation of likelihood by the speaker. 'They will probably have forgotten to turn off the heating over the holidays.' 'Hopefully' is semantically desiderative (expressing desire). Admittedly, there's probably a shade of optimism, which overlaps slightly with the modal term. But I'd say it's the near-juxtaposition of two 3-syllable speaker-comment pragmatic markers that's off-putting. 'They will probably help us out in the future. I hope they do, anyway' works.